# ahah fields in custom form stopped working after migration

Tags: javascript, ajax

I migrated my drupal 6 website to a new machine. my custom form with ahah-fields are not working in the new server.

```
          OLD    =>  NEW
............................
ubuntu => 9.10   => 14.04
php    => 5.2.10 => 5.5.9
apache => 2.2.12 => 2.4.7
mysql  => 5.1.37 => 5.5.41
jquery => 1.2.6  => 1.2.6
```

I tried updating below modules (using drush):

```
ahah_helper   =>  6.x-2.1  => 6.x-2.2  
jquery_update =>  6.x-1.1  => 6.x-2.0-alpha1
jquery_update module updated:
      JQUERY => 1.2.6 => 1.3.2 
      jquery.form.js  =>  2.01  => 2.43
      ahah.js  => to  =>  1.1.2.1
```

ahah fields are select fields; after selecting a value in the first(parent) fields, all the below fields dissappears..

Please help..

Thanks in advance..